# Match cell against list and render term

Tags: excel, vba, function, countif

I've attempted this with regular excel functions. What I have is a list of keywords, and need to match it against a smaller list of terms.

For example, cell A2 has wholesale discount furniture

My list has:

```
discount
cheap
sale
bargain
```

I need something that will check the cell against the list and render "discount" in the cell.

Thus far, the best I've been able to do is

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A2,"*"&Sheet2!$I$2:$I$6&"*"))>0
```

Which tells me if any term from the list is in the cell. After this, it's just manually entering the terms that render as TRUE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this formula:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$I:$I,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(Sheet2!$I$2:$I$6)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet2!$I$2:$I$6,A2))),1))
```

[image]

The above formula may give false positves as it will find partial words, for example it will find `cheap` in `cheapest`.  If this is not your intent and you want to find full words only then use this modification:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$I:$I,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(Sheet2!$I$2:$I$6)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" " & Sheet2!$I$2:$I$6 & " "," " & A2 & " "))),1))
```

Comment: @ParthShah please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.